# An animated sci-fi movie with a fully armoured antagonist and a pale looking child

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, cyborg, psychic

This is one of the few movies I saw on one of my relative's computer screen when I was little. As I was too young to understand anything, it was approximately 15 to 20 years ago (I believe the movie couldn't have come out after 2000, but the quality of the pictures looked good enough that I have my doubts).

The movie I am looking for was fully animated. Potentially a Japanese animated movie, but I can't tell for sure, as I was too young to tell the difference between Japanese, English or any language. There may be blood in the movie, but I can't tell for sure. However, now that I'm looking back, the drawing style looked slightly Japanese, although it was more of the bloody kind (I could slightly compare its style to "Blood: The Last Vampire" (2000)). Maybe it had an Asian tone to it (e.g. it could be a Korean animated movie too).

One of the "bad guys" was a tall, heavy guy, in a very armoured suit. I can't tell whether he was wearing a suit, or if his body was enhanced because he survived an accident (although I have some form of memory about the latter). Most of his body was covered, but I remember his face not being covered. The most distinctive feature he had was the fact that he had a Minigun where one of his arm should be (a bit like Barret in Final Fantasy 7). I think the first time we see him, he's seen crushing a metallic ashtray with his other hand.

A battle scene in the movie includes the heavy guy having a shoot-out against a relatively thin guy (or should I say "normal-sized man"), fighting him with a machine-gun mounted vehicle (he wasn't the one driving; he was shooting from the back of the vehicle). While they were shooting at each others, I remember the heavy guy screaming (nothing in particular, he was just shouting continuous "AAAHH~!!" in pure rage). The fight didn't seem to happen in a city. It slightly looked like a battlefield. The fight ended with some form of explosion, probably killing off the heavy armoured guy.

The other noticable character was a young boy. He looked... pale, almost weird. His skin was almost green, otherwise he looked like a regular child. He seemed to have some psychic powers too: at some point, when he was feeling uneasy and sweating, a man picked a sample of blood from the back of his neck, using a portable device. But when the man was... either incapacitated or down, that boy broke the device containing his blood simply by looking at it.

At some point near the end of the movie, the pale looking boy and some people (with scientists among them) seemed to be inside a huge facility or underground hangar. There was a lot of space, although I can't remember if it was a factory, or if it was an underground weapon storage. The child was also giving some form of speech too, as all the lights turned on suddenly. The others were possibly surprised by what they were seeing.

One last detail I remember about that child is his smile. While it wasn't as scary as the Joker's, his grin was... kind of creepy, because of how he looked at the others with his small round eyes. He was oftenly grinning.

Overall, most of the scenes I remember were quite dark (mostly because there was little light, or it was night time). The two exception being the battle scene (although it was dark, there was a lot of muzzle fire), and the last underground scene with the boy.

When I asked my relative about the movie, all they could tell me was: "The coloured word 'Aiko' was written on the cover of the CD".

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm trying to further update my question with details as I read up the topics.

Comment: When you said "Aiko", I immediately thought of "Akira" (1988). It had 3 greenish children with psychic powers, but I don't remember an armored antagonist.

Comment: The pictures I looked up have some vibes, but it doesn't look like it's that one. But looking at the picture reminded me of another small detail (which I'm going to add to my question right away).

Comment: It sounds a bit like MD Geist or something like that. It might not be that exactly but there were lots of similar anime in the 80s and early 90s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, thanks to some comments which pointed out similar movies, I was able to find it by searching through "similar movies" one by one.

Its name wasn't anything like "Aiko". It actually was [**Spriggan (1998)**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164917/).

The movie included several creepy guys, though I remembered only 2 of them.

The heavily armoured guy I remembered was called [Fat Man](https://myanimelist.net/character/71049/Fat_Man). He was indeed heavily mechanised and had an embedded gattling-gun where his right arm should be.

The cigarette scene where he crushes a metallic ashtray happens at 0:18:00.

The shooting scene against a vehicle with a machine-gun does happen in the movie, at precisely 0:33:30. Though the heavy guy seems to be dead, it doesn't end with an explosion like I remembered.

The [young pale boy](https://myanimelist.net/character/19453/Colonel_MacDougall) was indeed pale, but his skin didn't look greenish. I forgot to mention that I had the feeling he was wearing a baseball cap (though I wasn't totally sure he did). Otherwise, he was wearing what I could qualify as "casual children clothings".

Around 0:35:45, he drops on the ground because of some form of... let's call it headache. Then, a suit guy comes by and seems to take a sample of a green liquid (or injects something into him) from the back of the child's neck. At 0:46:10, the child kills the guy with his psychic powers, then break the glass of the man's device by looking at it at 0:46:35.

Following these two scenes, he's mostly followed by 2 scientists.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was made by the same people who did Akira, which means the cover probably mentioned it.